# Apache Camel SQL component select all records in a batch mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, apache-camel

I'm using apache camel as an ETL from (`select *...`) PostgreSQL to (`insert...`) MariaDB .

In the PostgreSQL there are a lot of records (more then 1M) and I want to do it in a batch way.

I've tried with several flag (`batchCount`, `batchSize`) but non of them worked.

I've also search in Apache Camel docs, without any success.

```
from("sql:SELECT * FROM my_schema.trees?dataSource=#postgersqlDataSource&batch=true")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .process(ex -> {
                log.info("batch insert for single table");
                List<Map<String, Object>> rows = ex.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                log.info(String.format("Value: %s", rows.size()));
            })
            .to("stream:out");
```

But the program crashed because it load everything to the memory (with 1 records it worked of course).

Any advise?

it runs overs `Spring boot`.

Answer (score 1):

The `batch` option is only for producer (eg to).
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/sql-component.html

Instead take a look at `outputType=StreamList` where you can combine this with split EIP (in streaming mode) to process the rows without loading all into memory.

This also mean you process 1 row at a time

```
from sql
  split
    process (1 row here)
```